# How to control play section of Video using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm making app using MPMoviePlayerController and I want to make special function.

What I want to function is like this.
If I play movie, player will stop after few second (ex: 30sec).
If I click play button, player has to play from 30sec to next stop point.

For me to realize this function, I've used `initialPlaybackTime` and `endPlaybackTime` option of `MPMoviePlayerController`.

But, this function didn't work like my thought.

```
mplayer.initialPlaybackTime = 0;
mplayer.endPlaybackTime = 10;
[mplayer play];
....
[mplayer pause];
....    
mplayer.initialPlaybackTime = 10;
mplayer.endPlaybackTime =30;
[mplayer play];
```

And, mplayer is played again from 0 to 10, not from 10 to 30.

Have another way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the initialPlaybacktime, did you try to set the currentPlaybackTime property? I'd give that a try:

```
[mplayer setCurrentPlaybackTime:10];
```

or, using the dot notation:

```
mplayer.currentPlaybackTime = 10;
```